# Data not capturing using Selenium web driver

Tags: java, html, selenium

I am trying to capture the product description from a webpage using ID and tagname but when I print it, it is showing blank. However I think I have used correct locators to locate the element.

Page Source

```
    <div id="item-description-block" class="layout-container layout-container-background clearfix">
<h2>About this item</h2>
<div id="social_share" class="details-row" onclick="javascript:clickPDP('Share','123070751499');">
<div class="details-row clear_both">
<div id="inspirational_copy">
<p>The big plus: Our new formula now helps strengthen skin's own moisture barrier. More moisture stays in. Skin feels soft, springy. Has a healthy-looking glow.</p>
</div>
```

Web Driver Code

```
driver.get("http://www.debenhams.com/webapp/wcs/stores/servlet/prod_10701_10001_123070751499_-1");
WebElement description =driver.findElement(By.id("inspirational_copy").tagName("p"));
String description1 = description.getText();
```

Comment: I want the string in paragraph - The big plus: Our new formula now helps strengthen skin's own moisture barrier. More moisture stays in. Skin feels soft, springy. Has a healthy-looking glow.

Comment: Thanks @RemcoW, I tried this but same results as this paragraph is still not visible in output. Any other way you think can help.

Comment: I have edited my answer, please take a look at it. A welcome message prevented me from getting the text, this might be your issue aswell.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I just tested it in Python and if you replace `By.id("inspirational_copy").tagName("p")` with a valid css selector you can then use `getText()` to get the text you're looking for.

```java
driver.get("http://www.debenhams.com/webapp/wcs/stores/servlet/prod_10701_10001_123070751499_-1");
WebElement description =driver.findElement(By.cssSelector("div[id='inspirational_copy']>p"));
String description1 = description.getText();
```

I did notice when I arrived on the page I got a welcome message. This message prevented me from getting the text. After closing it I could get the element and the text without problems.

```
WebElement close = driver.findElement(By.cssSelector("button[title='Close']");
close.click()
```

Comment: I think this cannot be a problem (Welcome Message)as I am able to fetch other piece of data from it, Only issue is with this paragraph which I am looking for. Can you try in java if you can manage to get this text.

Comment: Unfortunately I cant try it in Java. Did you try the suggestion. Can't hurt to give it a shot.

Comment: Thank you very much @RemcoW. I am now able to get this paragraph after closing the welcome message with the code you provided. 'WebElement close = driver.findElement(By.cssSelector("button[title='Close']");
close.click()'

Comment: The idea worked to close the welcome message. Problem solved :)

Comment: Glad you got it working. Please accept my answer to indicate this question has been solved.

Answer (score 0):

You can solve this problem easily by using xpath as locator

```
driver.findelement(By.xpath("//div[@id='inspirational_copy']/p"));
String description1 = description.getText();
```

Hope this will get the text you want.

Comment: I already tried this but unfortunately not getting the output. Have you tested it at your end if this is working and giving you the desired output. Which browser are you testing in.

Comment: It is issue with the welcome message.First write the script for closing that and then use gettext() method.i am working on firefox 46 it is working.

Comment: Which selenium version is compatible with Firefox 46?

Comment: selenium 2.53 and firefox 46

Answer (score 0):

```
String description1 = driver.findElement(By.xpath("//*[@id="inspirational_copy"]/p")).getText();
```